# How to separare backreference and alphanumberic values in psql

Tags: regex, backreference

I have a field that contains a string (Column name of another table)

**"call_records_2001.start_time"**

I need to replace it with

**"call_records_2002.start_time"**

I wanted this should be working for similar patterns, call_records_2001.end_time, call_records_2001.duration, etc

So I tried to use Regular expression back-reference as below,

```
  `regexp_replace('call_records_2001.start_time','(.*)2001(.*)','\12002\2','gi')`
```

But here it is taken as \12002 instead of \1

So how can I separate \1 from 2002 ?

Also, I tried ${1} , <1> but these were not separating the data as I expected.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it PostgreSQL? It [works there](https://rextester.com/FBWGD48100).

Comment: yes it is postgres

Comment: I tried using \\12002 and It is working fine as I expected. But I am not sure that if it will be working in all scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this, we just need to use `\\`  instead of `\` in back reference as below,

```
regexp_replace('call_records_2001.start_time','(.*)2001(.*)','\\12002\\2','gi')
```

It is working as I expected.

Comment: It is the same replacement pattern. You just have some setting that makes ``\`` be parsed as part of string escape sequences.